# textbox calculator with parsing function to arithmetic function

Tags: javascript, calculator

What I'm trying to do is have 2 text boxes that connect to one button. When the button is clicked, it calls a function to parse the 2 text box entries and then perform an addition (2 seperate functions). Can anybody point out what I'm missing on this? I keep getting `num1` as undefined when I call it in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>.</title>
</head>
<body>
Number1: <input type='text' id='num1'><br>
Number2: <input type='text' id='num2'><br>
<br>
<button onclick='add()'>Add</button>

<div id='toUser'></div> 

<script>
    var user = document.getElementById('toUser');
    var n1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;

    function parsing()
    {
    var num1mod = parseFloat($('n1')).value;
    var num2mod = parseFloat($('n2')).value;

        if (isNaN(num1mod || num2mod))
        {
        user.innerHTML = ('Please enter a valid number');
        }
                    else  
        {
        add();
        }
    }

    function add() 
    {
    parsing(); 
    return num1mod + num2mod;
    user.innerHTML = (return)

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 function parsing()
 {
     var user = document.getElementById('toUser');
     var n1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
     var n2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
     var num1mod = parseFloat(n1);
     var num2mod = parseFloat(n2);

    if (!isNaN(n1) || !isNaN(n2))
    {
      user.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid number';
    }else{
      var total =  num1mod + num2mod;
      user.innerHTML = total;
   }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it removed one error but num1,n1, num1mod all still return as undefined.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code:

1. `$('num1')` appears to be jQuery or some other library. From the tags though it doesn't look like you are using jQuery.
2. If you are using jQuery, `$('num1')` is an invalid selector. It should be `$('#num1')`
3. If you are using jQuery, it should be `.val()` rather than `.value` and it should be inside the preceding parenthesis `($('#num1').val())`, not outside.

**Native JavaScript:**

```
var num1mod = parseFloat(n1, 10);
var num2mod = parseFloat(n2, 10);
```

**jQuery:**

```
var num1mod = parseFloat($('#num1').val(), 10);
var num2mod = parseFloat($('#num2').val(), 10);
```